# Google Webmaster crawler showing internal links I cannot find

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, links, googlebot

I've got the crawler showing links that appear to be double URL encoded links.
Specifically links that are `%2520` instead of `%20` or .

As far as I know I've fixed this a while ago by removing special characters and spaces, but let the URL handler still be able to handle these links. I go to the `Linked From` page it lists as source of the issue, and I cannot find anywhere the link it describes.

Does anyone know what's going on?

It seems that the links are ok on my end, and Google is converting the `%` to `%25` and can't go to the page after, because my setup with IIS cannot handle a `%2520`

Comment: 'As far as I know'....Have you double checked your site with webcrawlers such as Screaming Frog and/or Xenu Link Sleuth?

Comment: yes, I've used Xenu. The thing is that I'm using a route to handle pages based on information in a database. I'm stripping the text of non-alphanumeric characters, so `two words`, `two-words` and `TwoWords`, as well as a few others still show the same data. The reason this is an issue is that if google got to `Two Words` once and indexed it (as `Two%20Words`) and looks again later, it will keep causing the issue, even though I fixed all internal links. The way to fix this, would be to redirect all pages to the url containing the stripped values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Webmaster Tools is often very behind. Some metrics are two days behind, and other data can be weeks behind. If these encoded URLs no longer exist, let it 404 and do not worry about it. If they do continue to resolve, you may want to break these links somehow and let nature take it's course. BTW- double encoding is common when a URL is read that contains URL encoding. If your original links do not have encoding, then it was nothing you did. It is not uncommon that scrapers come by and add the encoding that then is read by a search engine and encoded again. I have seen this go on for 5 or 6 times before it finally ends though conceivably this can continue forever perhaps. I always avoid encoding and I especially avoid spaces though I generally do not give that advice. Spaces are fine.